# Magento website backups

Tags: magento2.2.2, backup, ftp, local-storage

Sorry for the low level of this question; I'm a beginner, and I'm kinda unaware of the extent of my own ignorance at this point.

I need to back up my Magento 2.2.2 website before upgrading to v2.4.

So I transferred all the files (minus ~12k files, which gave an error in FileZilla) to local storage using FTP. The resulting directory is over 800 GB in size.

Is this a normal size for a Magento website? Is there a faster/more convenient way to create a full backup?

*(Already tried System -> Tools -> Backups in the admin panel, and I can only make Database backups. System or Database & Media backups produce a "We can't create this backup right now" error).*

Answer (score 0):

The best I know to backup the files is via CPanel. Usually you backup the home directory, MySQL database and emails. Will generate the .gz files. You may save on your computer and upload to your root directory.

Please don't go for full backup once it for migrating to another server. Once it's done, you are okay to migrate Magento version and upload the files in the same path.

Regarding the sizes, it depends on the size of your website and database. you may check the size on CPanel as well, on Disk Usage tab. As an example, I have just backup my website... It has 1.8Gb of home directory and 600Mb of MySQL database

[image]